# Ping a network card from a different network card

Tags: networking

I have a server with 2 network cards:

**NIC1**: 192.168.**1**.50 / 255.255.255.0 / 192.168.1.1

**NIC2**: 192.168.**195**.50 / 255.255.255.0 / 192.168.195.1

A web application is installed on the first NIC.

The problem is that a PC (192.168.**195**.51) is connected on the 2nd network card. When I try to open the application, it doesn't open and I can't ping NIC1 from this PC.

Is it possible to access the first NIC1 if you're connected to the 2nd NIC?

[image]

Comment: Is the PC connected _directly_ to that network card, or through a switch? (Does 192.168.195.1 actually exist? What gateway is the PC configured to use?)

Comment: The PC is in a different network. You need routing between the two.

Comment: The PC is connected to a switch, the 192.168.195.1 is the gateway
@gronostaj any idea what the routing command should be like?

Comment: What's your goal here, actually? Why do you have two NICs? It could be that you're solving a problem that you have created and the proper solution lies elsewhere. We need more info.

Comment: Commands depend on the operating system. If this is Windows, Microsoft has the answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/route_ws2008

Comment: @gronostaj I made an image that should explain my issue better : https://i.imgur.com/9DrcM8u.png
Basically I'm trying to reach 192.168.1.50 from the PC that is 192.168.195.51 where this PC is connected to the 2nd NIC 192.168.195.50
@ Peregrino69 Thank you for this, I will follow the documentation and see.

Comment: I added the image to the question. In general it's better to put answers and new info directly in the question by [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1770051/edit) it than answering in comments. That way all relevant info is readily available.

Comment: @VeralianIV did you have a chance to look at the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Your PC uses a different [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) `192.168.195.0/24` then the "application's subnet" it's trying to access (which is bound to the subnet `192.168.1.0/24`). Same goes for using ping between different subnets. You have two options to make this work:

- put them into the same subnet
- setup appropriate routing between the subnets

The first option will be easier to implement but eventually it depends on the reason why decided to put them into different subnets in the first place.

If you don't know how to setup the routing, there are plenty of HowTos available for common OSs. Feel free to ask if you have specific problems, but please provide the appropriate details first.

Note: there are some other options like adding a second IP to the NIC etc. depending on the the servers capabilities

Comment: `(on the server)` Server isn't the default gateway for PC though, so what he really needs is a route on the PC (so that traffics for `192.168.1.50` won't go to the `192.168.195.1` host) As for the server, it's more of an ARP problem. With regards to that, what the OP wants would work by default on Linux (see the arp_filter and arp_ignore sysctls). No idea how Windows deals with this. (Perhaps an indirect route would make it work anyway? With `192.168.195.50` as the nexthop.)

Comment: Btw multiple subnets here is really just a "result". Unless you bridge the two NICs on the server so that they "become one" and "join/merge" the networks (broadcast domains), it wouldn't make much sense to `put them into the same subnet`.

Comment: @TomYan bridging subnets takes place on layer 2, it does not change the fact that you still have multiple subnets on layer 3, unless you mean some kind of bridging I'm not aware of - in this scenario routing is the way to go. As for your first comment, I don't see how adding a route on the PC would help, the route needs to be added on the system that has access to both subnets, which, in this case, is the server.

Comment: `it does not change the fact that you still have multiple subnets on layer 3` which is why I said multiple subnets was a result (of the fact that there are two broadcast domain). (This is purely "assuming* the case is an XY-problem. Not that I was saying like "just bridge them".) Pay attention that the OP is not trying to reach *another host* on the other subnet by using Server as a gateway, but Server itself with its other IP. (And regardless, I have already made it clear why you need a route on PC. If you couldn't parse that, you are probably not familiar with networking at all.)

Comment: @TomYan I don't follow, reaching an endpoint on a different subnet - PC (on subnet 1) tries to reach the server/application (on subnet 2) - in my view - is exactly what the OP is trying to do?! But you are correct, the routing has to take place on the gateway/router wich is not necessarly the server. PS. You don't know me, don't make any assumptions about my background knowledge, this is extremely rude and does not comply with this site's code of conduct!

Comment: It has nothing to do about rudeness. These are literally fundamental ideas of networking and I'm no expert myself at all. (I don't even know much about VLAN.) And I can't really explain every bits by commenting because *that* violates the CoC/rule here. What I can suggest is you may want to look deeper into the difference between direct and indirect routes (or in other words, how does route actually work when the hosts are in the same broadcast domain, assuming you are using a direct route as usual / you should).

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it if it makes you happy.